# How to ensure that no two checkboxes are enabled in android

Tags: android

I have a custom list view and each item of it has a check box and a text field. I want to disable the check box in every other row of the list view if the check box of the first row is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are stating that if the **first** check box is clicked all the others should be disabled, do a check in your onBindView() to see if the checkbox is checked. if it is, set a value to say that it is, and for all the following list view entries set the checkbox to disabled.

In your `onCheckChangedListener():`

```
 checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked()){
                firstCheckboxChecked = true;
            }
    });
```

Then in your onBindView for the rest:

```
if(firstCheckBoxChecked){
    checkbox.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: There is no three checkboxes. I have only I checkbox

Comment: the answers was changed

Answer (score 0):

Here I am putting some rough solution which will help you.

```
classs model
{

boolean status;

model(boolean status){

    this.status=status;
}
}


List<model> list_model= new ArrayList<>();
list_model.add(false);
list_model.add(false);
list_model.add(false);
list_model.add(false);
```

add this model with listview adapter.

//Adapter coding

```
checkbox.checked(check)
```

//write below code in checkbox.setOncheckedItemSelect method.

//you will get already checked parameter in that method.which will put into list

```
list_model.add(checked);
```

//here call listview notify datasetchangedListener.

Answer (score 0):

create a boolean variable `isFirstEnbled` in your adapter. then on click first item's checkbox set this value as `isFirstEnbled=true` .
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

This recreate the view with `isFirstEnabled` set as true

Comment: Can you explain more of how to achieve this.